# How to get a screenshot using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, screenshot

I need to get screenshot step by step on my selenium Webdriver code, but when I insert the getscreenshot code my test stop.

Code:

```
public class Rule {

protected static WebDriver driver;

public void getscreenshot(String folder, String file) throws Exception {      

    File screenshotFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
     FileUtils.copyFile(screenshotFile, new File("Evidencias\\"+folder+"\\"+file+".png"));
}}
```

On Step Class:

```
public class Steps extends Execute {

@Given("acessei a url do portal")
public void AcessoUrl() {
       Execute Executar = new Execute();
       Executar.abrirBrowser();
}

@And("cliquei no botao de Login com email")
public void Login() throws Exception {
    Execute Executar = new Execute();
    getscreenshot("Login","01 - Acessando URL"); 
    Executar.Login();
```

How can I fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use google for such common questions.

Here you go: https://www.guru99.com/take-screenshot-selenium-webdriver.html